# Why are torrc modifications required for a bitcoin hidden service on the wiki?

Tags: bitcoind, tor

According to [the wiki](https://bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/setting-up-a-tor-hidden-service) the torrc file requires the following settings:

```
ControlPort 9051 
CookieAuthentication 1 
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
```

However, if you simply run bitcoind.conf with `onlynet=onion` and `listenonion=1` you'll get the same result as `getnetworkinfo` shows that ipv4/6 in unreachable while onion is reachable.

What gives? Why do we need the torrc config change as  the wiki states?

Answer (score 0):

Laanwj: it's not necessary in every case, bitcoin core can create its own hidden service, but it needs to be able to connect to tor's control port; see https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md. in some linux distributions (debian-ish) this is possible without changes to torrc, you might need to add your user to some group, in others you do need changes